# Add API key to a header in a DRF browsable API page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, browser

I am enabling token/api-key authentication on my API. But once I enable it, I can no longer use the browsable API page of the DRF. I know I can disable the authentication while developing, but this is a question of curiosity: Can I add an api-key to the header of each request sent to the browsable API page? Can I do that by tweaking the Browser settings? Or is it possible to tweak the Browsable API page itself and hardcode the api-key into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to handle the situation is to add the [**`SessionAuthentication`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) to the **`DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`** section in your settings

```
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
}
```

More precisely,

```
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
}
if DEBUG:
    REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"].append(
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication"
    )
```

By doing this, you can ***either*** use your `APIKey` or `session key` to authenticate the requests.

Comment: But I suppose it is not the same with permission classes? I am using restframework-api-key third party app. And it works with permissions: ```"rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey"```. But your suggestion is nice, I am using ```if DEBUG``` trick to overwrite the default permission classes now.

Comment: Authentication and authorization are two different things. In your case, I'm wondering why they've implemented it as a *authorization*

Comment: I think it is done that way in order to enable per-view/api-endpoint based control. So the same user maybe authorized to use some part of my system but needs to provide an api-key if he wants to use the other part.